# Cos'è un "coltello catalano"?

Tags: meaning, regional

Nel romanzo *Mille anni che sto qui*, di Mariolina Venezia, ho letto questa frase (grassetto mio):

> Qualcuno gli puntò al collo un **coltello catalano**.

Questo fatto accade vicino a Grottole (Basilicata) durante il Risorgimento. Infatti, quello che punta questo coltello è un brigante che fa parte di un gruppo il cui capo è [Carmine Crocco Donatelli](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carmine_Crocco).

Qualcuno di voi saprebbe dirmi cos'è un "coltello catalano"? Ho cercato alla voce "catalano" di parecchi dizionari, ma non ho trovato questa espressione.

Comment: Questa espressione mi ha veramente incuriosita: sono catalana, ma non ho idea di cosa possa essere un "coltello catalano".

Comment: Ci vorrebbe forse più contesto. Messo così potrebbe essere qualsiasi cosa da un coltello fatto in Catalogna ad un tipo speciale di coltello con determinate caratteristiche, magari usato in passato. Il romanzo è ambientato ai giorni nostri?

Comment: Hai ragione, @Easymode44: ho cercato di aggiungerlo alla domanda.

Comment: Con una rapida ricerca trovo questa espressione sulle pagine di alcuni coltellinai e in traduzioni italiane dei _Misteri di Parigi_ di Sue e del _Conte di Montecristo_ di Dumas, che in effetti nell'originale usano _couteau catalan_. Che sia un calco dal francese?

Comment: @DaG: Può darsi che sia [così](https://www.lecouteau.info/couteaux-r%C3%A9gionaux-traditionnels/le-catalan/). La cosa curiosa è che sembra trattarsi di un coltello tradizionale della Catalogna Nord (cioè, la parte della Catalogna che è in Francia).

Comment: Ah, interessante, @Charo. Questo spiegherebbe perché ne parlino autori francesi (anche se il mio campione non è esattamente molto ampio).

Answer (score 4):

Un coltello catalano, oppure, in catalano *navalla catalana*, è stato un coltellino pieghevole molto popolare nel secolo XVIII, il cui manico ha la forma caratteristica che si vede nella fotografia:

[image: Coltello]
[Fonte fotografia](http://dhb3yazwboecu.cloudfront.net/668/products/una_mica_d_tot/navalles/wpn20_400.jpg)

Alcuni tipi di coltelli catalani, secondo questa [fonte](http://www.kortiks.ru/litera/katalonskie_noji)  (nomi in catalano):

- Solsonesa.
- Ripollesa.
- Gavatxa.
- Navalla de punta tallada.
- Navalla de podar.

Vicino a Perpignan puoi trovare un negozio dove acquistare uno: [Couteaux catalans Christian Ibergay](https://g.page/artisancouteliercatalan?share).

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE, @LinoBordin. Qual è la fonte di tutta questa informazione e della fotografia (che non mi sembra affatto un coltello del XVIII secolo)? E in quale lingua sono scritti questi vocaboli? Sembra una miscela tra catalano e castigliano (con troppe maiuscole). E sei sicuro che è "solonesa"? Quello della fotografia sembra un coltello fabbricato a Solsona, quindi dovrebbe essere "solsonesa".

Comment: Ciao, grazie! :)

La fonte è questa qua: http://www.kortiks.ru/litera/katalonskie_noji, ma com'è in russo non mi pareva giusto metterla qua.

Dopo ho visto che c'è un'altra fonte in spagnolo: https://www.cuchillosnavajas.com/blog/las-navajas-catalanas.html

Sì, la parola sarebbe "Solsonesa", un errore di battitura. :)

Comment: Ho fatto qualche altra correzione perché, così com'erano quelle parole, l'orografia non era né catalana né castigliana.

Comment: Siamo sicuri di avere il permesso di mostrare quella fotografia? Perlomeno se ne dovrebbe indicare la fonte.

Comment: Interessante, ma la fonte russa parla dell'espressione italiana “coltello catalano”? Se no, per quanto probabile, non possiamo essere certi che sia la stessa cosa menzionata in quel romanzo. Ricordiamo che fra una lingua e l'altra le locuzioni cambiano: _French leave_, insalata russa, _nuit américaine_...

Comment: @DaG:   E anche, per esempio, "tortilla francesa" o "truita a la francesa", che sarebbe una frittata fatta in un modo che, per quanto ne so, 
non è per niente solito in Francia.

Comment: Nel romanzo quello che si capisce è che sia soltanto un coltello che è di tipo catalano. Non si riferisce ad un'espressione pura italiana.

Comment: Vediamo qua esempi: https://www.negozio-coltelli.it/coltellini/5265-navaja-catalana-hueso-hoja-82-cms.html e https://www.coltellieforbicimilano.com/prodotto/coltello-catalano-virginia/

Comment: Ho inserito la fonte della foto. :)

Comment: Ah, ecco: la fotografia è tratta da [questo sito](http://www.artdelaterra.cat/comprar-navalles-artesanes-pintades-pirogravades-senyeres-estelades/navalla-catalana-senyera-pintada) (continuo a non essere sicura che [si possa pubblicare qui](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327528/)). A quanto pare, si tratta del [negozio di due disegnatori catalani](http://www.artdelaterra.cat/qui-som).

Answer (score 2):

capito qui per caso alla ricerca di fonti da indicare a un amico, ma il caso vuole che ne sappia qualcosa; effettivamente il termine "coltello catalano" o "alla catalana" nasce nei romanzi d'appendice dell'800, e poi viene utilizzato a volte per indicare un grosso coltello a serramanico, tipo quelli utilizzati nei romanzi suddetti dagli immancabili "cattivi"; non si sa perché proprio catalano, naturalmente in Catalogna esistevano coltelli del genere ma come in altre zone della Spagna; in Italia tra collezionisti si definisce a volta come catalano (impropriamente) qualunque coltello con caratteristiche simili, e a volte i fabbricanti definiscono così qualche loro modello, spesso senza ragione; il termine si riferisce alla Catalogna spagnola e non a quella francese, che per varie ragioni è conosciuta come Roussillon e dove si usano coltelli con caratteristiche diverse; le tipologie di coltelli catalani indicate da alcuni sono moderne, non rappresentative dei coltelli catalani dell'800, qui un esemplare della Catalogna francese, lungo circa 50 cm aperto
https://www.dropbox.com/s/d3nrhj6m9wkujuc/s-ca12a.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Benvenuto/a su Italian.SE e grazie del tuo contributo. Alcuni mesi fa, feci un po' di ricerca e, in effetti, in Francia e in francese  si usano questi termini, *couteau catalan*, per chiamare un coltello di questo tipo (si veda il [commento](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/12705/cos%c3%a8-un-coltello-catalano#comment29409_12705) di @DaG e la definizione di "couteau catalan" sul [*Trésor de la langue française*](https://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/catalan)). Sai di qualche testo italiano dell'Ottocento o del Novecento che usi "coltello catalano" per un coltello di questo genere?

Comment: C'è anche sul Larousse:  https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/catalan/13710/locution?q=couteau#169517.  E questa citazione in francese sembra confermare che "couteau catalan" si usava già nell'Ottocento, https://fr.thefreedictionary.com/catalan%2C+ane, che appare anche qui: http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/Catalane/fr-fr/: la definizione e la citazione provenirebbero dal dizionario Ottocentesco [*Le Littré*](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise).